# Рекурсия по DOM дереву

Tags: javascript

```
const search = (element, tagName = '') => {
    const wrapper = [];
    const goDownRecursively = (wrapper, target, tagName) => {
        if (!target.children) return;
        const element = [...target.children].filter((item) => {
            item.tagName === tagName.toUpperCase()
        });
        wrapper.push(...element);
        [...target.children].reduce((prev, cur) => {
            [...prev].concat(goDownRecursively(wrapper, cur, tagName))
        }, []);
    };
    goDownRecursively(wrapper, element.body, tagName);
    return wrapper;
};
search(document, 'li');
```

Пытаюсь написать рекурсию по DOM дереву для поиска элемента по тегу
М.б подскажете,где тут ошибка
P.S про `getElement*` в курсе, смысл именно написать свой велосипед чтобы разобраться.

Comment: проблем в злоупотреблении стрелочными функциями.

Comment: не хватает как минимум два return

Comment: @Grundy Не подскажете в чем злоупотребление?Тут вроде контекст нигде не теряется и где не хватает двух return(один наверно в reduce , а второй)?

Comment: в разнице `()=>result` и `()=>{result}`. Плюс все смешано настолько что тяжело понять, что вообще делается. `reduce` вообще тут не нужен тебе

Comment: @Grundy Я возможно что-то путаю ,но если в arrow function нет тела,а сразу возвращается результат,то обе записи (()=>result и ()=>{result}) равнозначны, а с помощью reduce я хочу рекурсивно по дереву идти

Comment: обе записи не равнозначны. рекурсивно ты идешь в goDownRecursively, поэтому тебе не нужен reduce, нужен обычный цикл.